# How to read rotated PDF using Ghostscript?

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I have this rotated PDF file, and I need to convert it to text file, using Ghostscript app.
[image]

How can i do that? I'm using basic parameters, and it's reading text "regular" way (top-left to down-right). I need it to read bottom-left to top-right.

```
-sDEVICE=txtwrite -o"C:\GS_temp_file.txt" "C:\test.pdf
```

Comment: The txtwrite device, in its default setting, tries to output a simple text file which matches the layout of the original file. So yes, I'd expect it to produce a text file with the text oriented as you have it. If you don't want that, then use one of the other output formats and read the co-ordinates yourself. Or rotate the page first (set the media size to landscapeusing DEVICEWIDTHPOINTS and DEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS, and set FIXEDMEDIA) then use -dFitPage. The Fit page algorithm will realise the content fits better rotated and will rotate the page. That should produce text oriented horizontally.

Comment: Not sure if I follow, so you're suggesting sth like this?

`-DEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=1600 -DEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=900 -dFIXEDMEDIA -dFitPage -sDEVICE=txtwrite -o"C:\GS_temp_file.txt" "C:\Temp\pdf.pdf"`

Comment: Yes that's what I had in mind

Comment: Unfortunatelly - I've noticed no change here. Text is read as it used to be - from left-to right order as default.
It's also worth to mention that pdf can have multiple pages.

Comment: And txtwrite can produce multiple pages of output, use %d in the filename. Without an example file to look at I'm afraid I can't help any further though.